# Searching for Values

Tags: c#

This question pulls content and ideas from a good many of my other questions and their answers, and pulls a lot of things together.  I am quite satisfied with my approach here, but seeing as I'm refactoring my app, I might as well ask about my practices and get suggestions for improvements.

This is my search method (thank you for helping me with it, Heslacher):

```cs
private static void GetResults(ref string[] query, ref ObservableCollection<int> weight)
{
    int position = -1;

    foreach (string[] array in SearchKeys.Keys)
    {
        position++;
        int length = array.Length;
        int middle = length / 2;
        char firstCharMidArray = array[middle][0];

        foreach (string s in query)
        {
            if (s.Length == 0) continue;

            int min = array[middle][0] < s[0] ? middle : 0;
            int max = array[middle][0] <= s[0] ? array.Length : middle + 1;

            for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
            {
                weight.Add(0);

                if (array[i] == s)
                {
                    if (weight[position] == 0)
                    {
                        Data.SearchList.Add(SearchKeys.Pages[position]);
                    }
                    weight[position]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works by pulling data from this:

```cs
public static ResourceLoader resourceFile = new ResourceLoader();

    public static string[][] Keys = { resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSOneNote").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSMainMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSTextMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSTextBlockMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSTableMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSTableCellsMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSDrawMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSDrawnItemsMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSPictureMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSFileMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSAppBarsMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSCharmsMenu").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSKeyboardShortcuts").Split(' '),
                                      resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSColorPalate").Split(' ')
                                      /* more here... */ };

public static MenuItem[] Pages = { new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("OneNote").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.OneNote), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSMainMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.MainMenu), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSTextMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.TextMenu), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSTextBlockMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.TextBlockMenu), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSTableMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.TableMenu), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSTableCellsMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.TableCellsMenu), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSDrawMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.DrawMenu), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSDrawnItemsMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.DrawnItemsMenu), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSPictureMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.PictureMenu), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSFileMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.File), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSAppBarsMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.AppBar), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSCharmsMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.Charms), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSKeyboardShortcutsMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.KeyboardShortcuts), Menus.SearchResult),
                                   new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSColorPalateMenu").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.ColorPalate), Menus.SearchResult) 
                                   /* more here... */ };
```

If you are not sure about any of the other code is called, and how it interacts with this, please feel free to ask for it or an explanation of what it does.   This works because each index of the collection of search values in `Keys` corresponds to the index of the matching `MenuItem` in `Pages`.  My keys are all stored in a .resw (resources) file for ease of adding multiple languages.  I have a feeling this isn't good, although it is simple enough to maintain, so please tell me everything wrong with it.

Comment: What is the primary use of this method ? Filling `weight` or adding to `Data.SearchList` ?

Comment: I see a dozen of these: `resourceFile.GetString("SearchWSOneNote").Split(' ')` and a dozen of these: `new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("OneNote").TrimStart(' '), typeof(WindowsData.OneNote), Menus.SearchResult)`: why don't you create methods to avoid copy-pasting these lines over and over again and merely changing one or two things? That would significantly improve the readability of that code.

Comment: @Heslacher The primary purpose is adding to `Data.SearchList`.

Comment: @BCdotNET Good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Var**

Use the `var` keyword when defining local variables where the right hand side of the definition makes the type obvious. This looks cleaner and saves time when it comes to changing types during refactoring.

e.g.

```
int position = -1;
```

should be

```
var position = -1;
```

You should also use `var` when declaring `foreach` and `for` loop iterators.

e.g.

```
for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
```

should be:

```
for (var i = min; i < max; i++)
```

**Design**

I hate seeing methods with reference variables and a void return. Unless you have a really good reason to do so, you should be returning one of those parameters. In this case you can actually do away with passing either in by reference:

- You don't appear to alter `query` at all, so you shouldn't pass it in using the `ref` keyword.
- It doesn't really make sense to pass in `weight` at all. Each time you call this method you'll be appending the weight data to your weight collection. If that's by design, you should state that explicitly using an `AddRange` or `Concat` method once you have the results from this function, but not by doing it in the function. This hides it as a side effect from a programmer.

So you can instead return `weight` normally:

```
private static ICollection<int> GetResults(ref string[] query)
```

**Naming**

`GetResults` might possibly be the only name other than `Compute` that could apply to *any* function.

Also, the name `array` isn't very descriptive of what that variable is. `key` would perhaps be closer to it. `compoundKey` closer still.

Comment: Excellent points, and I actually already had done some of this but forgot to implement it here.  However, my main question is not about `GetResults`, but rather my use of `Keys` and `Pages`, could you address this?

Comment: @Hosh250 is there a good reason for not using a dictionary? It looks like a one-to-one mapping with unique keys on the surface, which dictionaries are good at.

Comment: Well, no, that would actually be a great idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
int position = -1;

foreach (string[] array in SearchKeys.Keys)
{
    position++;
```

This is extraordinarily suspect.  In some languages, `foreach` or `forin` loops are faster than standard `for` loops.  In others, they work out about the same.  I'm pretty sure that in .NET, they're actually slower than regular `for` loops.

But with that said, `foreach` can sometimes improve readability, so they can still be nice to use.  However, in this case, we're going to need a loop index anyways, so why don't we just write a regular `for` loop?

```
for (int position = 0; position < SearchKeys.Keys.Length; ++position)
```

---

Overall, the method could benefit greatly from some comments.  You have none, and what you're doing isn't exactly simple or straight-forward.  In the question, you're offering thanks to someone for helping you write it.  If you required help writing it, then it's unlikely that you necessarily completely understand it.  So if you later spot a bug, or you need to re-implement this in a slightly different way, are you going to understand all of this?  Or if someone else is maintaining this, how much time do you want them to spend trying to figure out what the code does before they actually start improving it/fixing bugs/adding features/etc?

Search algorithms should generally be well-commented, or provide a link to some commonly used algorithm (like a wiki page or something) which you've implemented (or attempted to implement).